# Hide an HTML video element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend, webcam

I'm using `webcam easy js` for taking a picture to our clients. What I need is to hide the camera, because client shouldn't know that is being filmed. I tried to hide the element via **jQuery**, with `hide()` function but I get null when I call Ajax the moment the snap is beign taken. I tried to use **css** for hide it, but it doesn't work, and tried to use display:none, visibility:hidden, etc..
Can you help me? Sorry for the bad English.

- Script for the snap and call ajax servlet for processing image:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var webCamElement = document.getElementById("camera");
    var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const webcam = new Webcam(webCamElement, 'user', canvasElement, null);
    
    //$('#camera').style.display="none";
    //$('#camera').attr('visibility', 'hidden');
    //$('#camera').attr('display', 'block');
    webcam.start();
        
    $('#checker').click(function(){
        picture = webcam.snap();
        alert(picture);
        $.post('TestCamera', {param: picture}, function(response){
            if (response === 'error'){
                alert('Error you should stay in front of camera');
            }else{
                window.location.replace('QuestionAndAnalyze.jsp'); /* redirect*/
            }
        }); /*END servletCall*/
    }); /*END click*/
    
});/* END ready*/
```

HTML elements:

```html
<video id="camera"></video>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkVision" id="checker">
<label for="checkVision">I read tips</label>

<form action="startSurvey" method="GET">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

I want to hide the `<video id="camera">` and using it for passing it to ajax servlet call.

Comment: You are filming someone without consent? That's illegal.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is asking for help with something illegal.

Comment: yep i know, but this data is used for medical purpose, and doctor take care about this particular

Comment: Doesn't matter who or what it is for, taking a picture of someone without he or she knowing isn't allowed. And a doctor should know better.

Comment: Come on he sign a document for certificate that stop be the lawyer of lost causes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the browser will ask for permission to use a camera. So your client will understand that he/she is being filmed.

[image]

You at least might try

```js
$('#camera').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

instead of

```js
$('#camera').attr('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/xxVVavN

Comment: Correct, but he know that is filmed, but he don't know when, in particular when he compile the survery in a specific case.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the camera would be working on the Doctor's laptop, not the patients'. Is that correct?

Comment: @GabrielePisapia You at least might try `$('#camera').css('visibility', 'hidden');` instead of `$('#camera').attr('visibility', 'hidden');`.

Comment: Yes it is, and doctor take care about documents that patient sign for takeing legally the picture of him